# NameError: name 'char' is not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a text game in python and i'm trying to debug the game right now.
I think this code I'm writing is supposed to type out the letters/characters one by one and make a typing effect.
here it is:

```
def setup_game():
### BACKSTORY TELLING
backstory = "something something boring backstory"
typeout(backstory)

def typeout(x):
    time.sleep(0.03)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    option = input('> ')
    if option.lower() == '> ok':
        title_screen()
    else:
        print("please try again\n")
        option = input('> ')

#Actual game
def start_game():
    print_location()
    main_game_loop()

setup_game()
```

but whatever i do it always gives me an error and i don't know how to fix it.
here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "textgame.py", line 612, in <module>
    setup_game()
  File "textgame.py", line 600, in setup_game
    typeout(backstory)
  File "textgame.py", line 604, in typeout
    sys.stdout.write(char)
NameError: name 'char' is not defined
```

all the lines referenced in the error are in the code from the top.

I did find another post about the:

```
time.sleep(0.03)
sys.stdout.write(char)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

part and i tried doing what the answer said but instead it just gave me a different error which is what i have now.
help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is char? I can't see where you have defined char.

Comment: have you tried: `sys.stdout.write(x)` ... `x` is the variable you're passing to the function, not `char`

Comment: @ThatBird shouldn't that just mean the characters of "backstory" one by one?

Comment: You'll have to call your function in a loop

Comment: @MatthewStory oh yeah, it works now. i don't get the error anymore. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
sys.stdout.write(x)
```

Because `char` is not defined in your code. You're passing `x` to the function.